# specifying a longtable not to split

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I am using longtable in my report as I have many tables that are longer than a page. To make it consistent, I am using longtable for all the tables. Many times because of page settings, a small table gets split into two across consecutive pages. Is there a way to specify to a longtable that don't split this table across pages? I know this defeats the purpose of longtable in a way, but I am looking for a work around.

Answer (score 3):

If you are `longtable` for all tables, then you also have the disadvantage that the tables do not float. If a short table is broken across pages this also means, that the table does not fit on the starting page. Moving it to the next page leaves a more or less large gap on the page before the table. You can circumvent this with package `afterpage`. In the preamble add:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

Then the table is put on the next page using `\afterpage`, but the following text still fills the current page:

```
\afterpage{%
  \begin{longtable}{...}
  ...
  \end{longtable}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that by using afterpage, the longtable behaves as an atomic table?

Comment: @damned No, it just starts at the top of the next page. Thus it stays on one page, if the table is not longer than one page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you'd want to do this as longtable doesn't have any specific formatting, it derives all its table formatting from the underlying `tabular` implementation. However if you put a `longtable` in a `minipage` it will not break. As the output routine is then not invoked you can not use the head and foot code of course but this makes a very long table that does not break over the page:

```
Overfull \vbox (441.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [2]
```

Which is the same behaviour as you would get from a long `tabular` at this point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 
text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\I'm a non & breaking& longtable\\
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```